# Configure Modern Team Site in SharePoint on premises server 2016

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, 2016, modern-experience

I'have configured SharePoint farm 2016! Now I want to configure SharePoint modern team site, Can anyone please suggest the steps for the same?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**As a Short answer**, you can't create a Modern site in SharePoint 2016 On-Prem yet!

- There is **no** Modern Team Site in SharePoint 2016 On-Prem yet!
- The release of ‘Feature Pack 2 for SharePoint Server 2016’ provides only use and build the SharePoint Framework WEB PARTS hosted in the classic web part pages of SharePoint Server 2016.

> **Note:** Modern Team Site Announced to be available in SharePoint 2019

**For more details,** check my related detail article  [SharePoint SPFX for SharePoint 2016](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/09/16/sharepoint-framework-for-sharepoint-server-2016/)

Answer (score 2):

SP 2019 supports Modern team and communication sites (not associated with O365 groups).

SP 2016 doesn't have support for Modern team and communication sites.

Read more on the thread [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint/Modern-Page-Experience-availability-in-SharePoint-2016-On-Prem/m-p/112157/highlight/true) and [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint/Choosing-between-SharePoint-Server-2016-and-SharePoint-Server/td-p/170026)